# Azure Durable Functions- concatenate multiple CreateTimer Tasks

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have this function:

```cs
[FunctionName("MultipleTimersOrchestrator")]
        public async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            log.LogInformation($"Starting process {DateTime.Now}");

            DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            await context.CreateTimer(deadline, CancellationToken.None);

            log.LogInformation($"Starting GetUser Tokyo {DateTime.Now}");
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("GetUser", "Tokyo"));
            log.LogInformation($"Ended GetUser Tokyo {DateTime.Now}");

            DateTime deadline2 = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            await context.CreateTimer(deadline2, CancellationToken.None);

            log.LogInformation($"Starting GetUser Seattle {DateTime.Now} ");
            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("GetUser", "Seattle");
            log.LogInformation($"Ended GetUser Seattle {DateTime.Now}");


            return outputs;
        }
```

My problem is that it is acting weird...Is it possible to have more than a timer awaited in one orchestratror function?
It seems, by the log, that the whole funtion is being executed after 5, and then after 10 seconds. I was expecting it to work like a `Task.Delay()`
Is that correct?Someone can explain that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, using multiple create timer calls is a very valid pattern, and it will function fairly similar to a `Task.Delay()`, though over the course of several function executions.

It appears that what is confusing you is the fact that Orchestrator functions [replay functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#reliability) everytime they call `await` on one of the `IDurableOrchestrationContext` API methods. This is how Durable Functions achieves the "durability" behind its name.

This can be very confusing for new developers, especially with logging. I would recommend using our replay-safe logger, which will not log messages that were already logged in previous replays. You can do that by adding the following to the top of your orchestration function.

`log = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(log);`

You can partially curb this replay behavior by using [extended sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#extended-sessions), which functionally allow the orchestration to resume where it left off assuming the messages that it calls `await` on return in a timely fashion.

Comment: Thanks Connor, you are totally right, great explanation